# How do you initialize a 2D array without setting its dimensions?

Tags: java, file-io, multidimensional-array

I am using a method which reads in a file and sets the size of a 2D array based on the first 3 lines. My method returns a `Room[][]` object and the method also sets the dimensions of the `Room[][]` object so that I cannot set it outside before doing the method. For example:

```
public Room[][] readRooms(String filepath) throws IOException
    {
        int numberOfRooms;
        int numRows;
        int numCols;
        Room[][] grid;

    try
    {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(filepath);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String next = null;

        numberOfRooms = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        numRows = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        numCols = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        grid = new Room[numRows][numCols];

        while((next = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
    catch{ //catch stuff }

return grid;
}
```

What I am attempting is to create a new Room[][] object in a main method in another class that does this:

```
Room[][] maze = readRooms(myfilepath);
```

However, Java is requiring that maze be defined before I can use it like this. Is it not possible to initialize a 2D array without explicitly declaring the dimensions?

Edit: The main method for those asking:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Room[][] maze;
    maze = readRooms("C:/Users/Blaise/Programming/csc300/Maze");
}
```

Comment: Show us the code where `maze` is defined, preferably an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also tell us the exact error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is your function `readRooms` is not `static`. Make it `static` and you will not need an instance of `Room` to call it. But you do need to handle the `IOException` in your caller (or add `throws IOException` to `main()`)

```
public static Room[][] readRooms(String filepath) throws IOException
```

Also, you cannot double declare `maze`'s type.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
  Room[][] maze;
  try {
    maze = Room.readRooms("C:/Users/Blaise/Programming/csc300/Maze");
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

**or**

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
  // Room[][] maze; // <-- not
  Room[][] maze = Room.readRooms("C:/Users/Blaise/Programming/csc300/Maze");
}
```

Comment: That was an error on my part, it was not doubly declared in my code originally but in my attempts to debug it I just copied over what I had been working on at the time of the question.

Answer (score 0):

An array's size is always fixed in Java. So you can't....Typically instead of using an array, you'd use an implementation of List here - usually ArrayList, but with plenty of other alternatives available.

You can create an array from the list as a final step, of course - or just change the signature of the method to return a List to start with

Answer (score 0):

Your main needs to either throw an IOException or surround `maze = readRooms(myfilepath)` with:

`try {...} catch (IOException) {...}`

Also you're declaring maze twice. Instead of writing

```
Room[][] maze;
Room[][] maze = readRooms(myfilepath);
```

Shorten it to

```
Room[][] maze = readRooms(myfilepath);
```

Like Eran said. Or if you really don't like that, do:

```
Room[][] maze;
maze = readRooms(myfilepath);
```

and Elliot is right too, `readRooms()` needs to be static.

I don't know if I answered your question or not, but at least it's some constructive criticism :).

**Edit**: I noticed you have `try {...} catch {...}` in your readRooms method... is this used to catch an IOException? If so, `readRooms()` doesn't need to throw an IOException at all.

Comment: No, the catch is for a separate exception.